# MYSQL - Iterating through and separating values in MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql

Consider a SQL table below:

| id | type | error_type | error_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | A A B B | 101 102 104 110 |
| 2 | P | B A A A A A | 104 104 105 106 107 108 |
| 3 | O | A B | 102 105 |
| 4 | I | B A B A | 109 107 110 110 |
| 5 | P | A A A | 107 108 110 |

Error_type can be combination of either A or B. Error_code listed in the forth column are corresponding to the error_type in third column. For example for the first record error_type A is for error_code 101, A is for 102, B is for 104 and B is for 110.

I want to convert above table in below format:

| id | type | error_code_A | error_code_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 101 102 | 104 110 |
| 2 | P | 104 105 106 107 108 | 104 |
| 3 | O | 102 | 105 |
| 4 | I | 107 110 | 109 110 |
| 5 | P | 107 108 110 |  |

I want to use MYSQL queries to achieve this output.
NOTE: There are few more columns and more than 50M records in the table. Also DBA has set a time out at 30 seconds

I tried cursors and procedures, but could not succeed due to lack of experience.

As another approach, I am also trying to use python scripts, but then I would need a way to connect with mysql DB in python, and get the output for all 50M records without timing out.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: Connecting python to mysql - plenty of tutorials for that, handling lots of rows - process them in batches. But you really should focus your question on one problem only.

Comment: 'but could not succeed due to lack of experience' - perhaps , but sql is poor at this sort of thing; Also please publish as text not linked images , and are the values always space delimited?

Comment: @Akina MySQL version is 8.0.34

Comment: @p-salmon yes, values are always space delimited.

Comment: Usng string functions convert your CSV to JSON array, parse it to separate values with identity then obtain needed output. For example..

Answer (score 0):

`JSON_TABLE()` can be used to turn the comma-separated strings into rows with ordinality, which can then be joined together and subjected to conditional aggregation to produce the desired result:

```
WITH cte_type as (
  SELECT id, type, e_type, rowid
  FROM mytable
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
           CONCAT('["', REPLACE(error_type, ' ', '","'), '"]'),
          "$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
              rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
              e_type VARCHAR(5) PATH "$"
              )
      ) AS et
),
cte_code as (
  SELECT id, type, e_code, rowid
  FROM mytable
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
           CONCAT('["', REPLACE(error_code, ' ', '","'), '"]'),
          "$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
              rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
              e_code VARCHAR(5) PATH "$"
              )
      ) AS ec
)
select ct.id, ct.type, group_concat(case when e_type = 'A' then e_code end ORDER BY cc.rowid SEPARATOR ' ') as error_code_A,
                       group_concat(case when e_type = 'B' then e_code end ORDER BY cc.rowid SEPARATOR ' ') as error_code_B
from cte_type ct
inner join cte_code cc on cc.id = ct.id 
           and cc.type = ct.type
           and ct.rowid = cc.rowid
group by ct.id, ct.type;
```

Result :

| id | type | error_code_A | error_code_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 101 102 | 104 110 |
| 2 | P | 104 105 106 107 108 | 104 |
| 3 | O | 102 | 105 |
| 4 | I | 107 110 | 109 110 |
| 5 | P | 107 108 110 | null |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y01Pb_QP)